# .NET 4.0 Generic Invariant, Covariant, Contravariant

Tags: .net, generics, .net-4.0, covariance, contravariance

Here's the scenario i am faced with:

```
public abstract class Record { } 

public abstract class TableRecord : Record { } 

public abstract class LookupTableRecord : TableRecord { } 

public sealed class UserRecord : LookupTableRecord { } 

public interface IDataAccessLayer<TRecord> 
    where TRecord : Record { } 

public interface ITableDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord> : IDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord> 
    where TTableRecord : TableRecord { } 

public interface ILookupTableDataAccessLayer<TLookupTableRecord> : ITableDataAccessLayer<TLookupTableRecord> 
    where TLookupTableRecord : LookupTableRecord { } 

public abstract class DataAccessLayer<TRecord> : IDataAccessLayer<TRecord> 
    where TRecord : Record, new() { } 

public abstract class TableDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord> : DataAccessLayer<TTableRecord>, ITableDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord> 
    where TTableRecord : TableRecord, new() { } 

public abstract class LookupTableDataAccessLayer<TLookupTableRecord> : TableDataAccessLayer<TLookupTableRecord>, ILookupTableDataAccessLayer<TLookupTableRecord> 
    where TLookupTableRecord : LookupTableRecord, new() { } 

public sealed class UserDataAccessLayer : LookupTableDataAccessLayer<UserRecord> { }
```

Now when i try to cast UserDataAccessLayer to it's generic base type `ITableDataAccessLayer<TableRecord>`, the compiler complains that it cannot implicitly convert the type.

When i try and use the `in` or `out` keywords in the interface declaration for the generic parameters, the compiler complains about **Invalid variance: The type parameter must be invariantly valid.**

I have the following abstract class:

```
public abstract class FileProcessor : IDisposable
{
    protected abstract ITableDataAccessLayer<TableRecord> CreateTableDataAccessLayer();
}
```

And a sample concrete implementation as follows:

```
public class UserFileProcessor : FileProcessor
{
            protected override ITableDataAccessLayer<TableRecord> CreateTableDataAccessLayer()
        {
            return new UserDataAccessLayer();
        }
}
```

**return new UserDataAccessLayer(); is where the compiler is complaining.**

Comment: Please post a short, but complete program that exhibits the problem, this way you can get specific answers as well.

Comment: Hi Lasse, i've made ammendents to my post as per your recommendation. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would like to see the entire UserDataAccessLayer definition as well, all methods, but hold on, let me add an answer and then you can see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you need to specify the out keyword for the interface if you want to use covariance.

[Link](https://web.archive.org/web/20210124210650/http://geekswithblogs.net/NewThingsILearned/archive/2009/09/30/covariance-in-.net-4.0.aspx)

Comment: I tried setting out on the generic parameters on the generic interface as well. But then the compiler gave me a different error:
Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TTableRecord' must be invariantly valid on...

Comment: If i apply the out keyword to the TTableRecord generic parameter in the generic ITableDataAccessLayer interface declaration, i get the following error:

Invalid variance: The type parameter 'TTableRecord' must be contravariantly valid on 'Csss.Data.DataAccessLayers.ITableDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord>.Delete(TTableRecord, bool)'. 'TTableRecord' is covariant.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with co- and contra-variance is that it imposes quite a bit of restrictions on the types involved, so it might not be applicable in all cases.

I managed to get your code to compile by making the following changes:

```
public interface IDataAccessLayer<out TRecord>
    where TRecord : Record { }

public interface ITableDataAccessLayer<out TTableRecord> : IDataAccessLayer<TTableRecord>
    where TTableRecord : TableRecord { }
```

Note:

- out added for IDataAccessLayer and ITableDataAccessLayer

This, however, means you're not restricted to using TTableRecord only in output positions in those types, which means:

- type for readonly properties (not for writeable properties)
- return type for methods
- out argument-types for methods

You can *not* use it for:

- writeable properties
- ref or non-out/ref parameters to methods

So likely, there is no way to make co- and contra-variance help you here.

Comment: Hi Lasse

Does not work. Add a method to ITableDataAccessLayer which uses type TTableRecord as a parameter or return type.

Comment: Is there anything else i can do to downcast a concrete type to a base generic type?

Comment: As I said, it has tons of restrictions, I doubt you can do what you want.